# EKCalender creates calendar but can't see it in iCal

Tags: iphone, ios5, icalendar

I am trying to create a new calendar in iCal. Now I am able to create a new Calendar with some name. But my problem is when I try to create to Local calendar I cant see it in calendar list. Any one have any idea about this? I have tried using all types of sources but not able to find exact solution for this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   NSMutableArray *arrAlarm = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
EKAlarm *alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:3600];  
EKAlarm *alarm2 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-3600];  //86400 1 day      
[arrAlarm addObject:alarm1];
[arrAlarm addObject:alarm2];
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *ekevent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
ekevent.title = strname;

NSLog(@"%@",ekevent.startDate);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d,yyyy"];
NSDate *date  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strdate];

// Convert to new Date Format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM"];
NSString *newDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]; 

//    dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
//    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

NSDate* firstDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:time];
NSDate* secondDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endtime];

NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate];

// Convert to new Date Format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:MM"];
NSString *t11 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:firstDate]; 
NSString *t12 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:secondDate]; 
NSDate *dt1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:t11];
NSDate *dt2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:t12];    

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"hh"];
NSString *hourstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                        [df stringFromDate:dt1]];
[df setDateFormat:@"mm"];
NSString *minstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                       [df stringFromDate:dt1]];
[df release];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date];
[components setHour: [hourstring intValue]];
[components setMinute: [minstring intValue]];
[components setSecond: 00];

//    NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];
[gregorian release];

ekevent.startDate = date;

ekevent.endDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:timeDifference sinceDate:date];
[ekevent setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
ekevent.alarms = arrAlarm;
[arrAlarm release];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:ekevent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

Try this code you will get the desired result.

Comment: Hey thank you for the solution, but I am able to create events for default type of calendar. I am trying to use new feature of ios5 that is we can create new calendar of specific events. And which can be view in iphone's calendar application's calendar list. I have problem in that. I am able to create Events as well as Calendar. But when I activate iCloude calendar, I can't see my calendar in List.